# Dart, Why are these two functions NOT independant?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two functions, one to get unbought items, one to get bought items.

Here is my problem: If I run these two lines

```
getBought()
print(getUnbought())
```

I will print out an empty list, or rather, getUnbought() starts returning an empty list everywhere in my whole application.

If I run `print(getUnbought())` alone, having never ran getBought() under the whole runtime, I will get a full list of items.

```
Future<List<Item>> getUnbought() async {
    await database;

    List products = await _database!.query("boughtItems");


    List<Item> result = availableProducts;

    for (var element in products) {
      result.removeWhere((unBought) => unBought.id == element["id"]);
    }
    return result;
  }

  Future<List<Item>> getBought() async {
    await database;

    List products = await _database!.query("boughtItems");

    List<Item> result = [];

    for (var element in products) {
      result.add(availableProducts.where((e) => e.id == element["id"]).first);
    }

    return result;
  }
```

Somehow, the first function influencing the others somehow, making it only return an empty list, when they should be fully independant of eachother.

availableProducts is a list of all items, that is in another file.

What am I missing.

Comment: Can you include how are using `getUnbought`

Comment: What happens if you run `print(getUnbought()); print(getUnbought());`?

Comment: Could be the issue is hiding in `await _database!.query("boughtItems");` or even in the getter for `database`.

Comment: It doesn't explain the behavior you're describing, but the two functions are *not* independent. `getUnbought` *mutates* the `availableProducts` list.  If you don't want that, then `getUnbought` should make a copy of `availableProducts` first: `var result = [...availableProducts];`.